# Manga where a guy is isekaied and trained by a system in a cultivation world; he thinks he is a mortal but everyone else thinks he is a master

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, cultivation

This manga is about a guy who is isekaied and trained by a system in a cultivation world. He thinks he is a mortal but everyone else thinks he is a peerless master. They give him respect where even his broken knife is a treasure. He gave his broken knife away. He has a gym of sorts and his paintings give enlightenment.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you remember any details of the art or the character's appearance?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Above Myriads](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/wu4pcna/above-myriads)***...?

From Baka-Updates:

> Tens of thousands of big shots grovel at his feet, yet he says, "I'm really just an ordinary mortal, though…"

The protagonist, Yi Feng, has transmigrated to a cultivation world where he's regarded as a peerless martial god, although he believes he's just a mortal. He practices martial arts against a wooden dummy in a training hall, and is so revered by other martial artists in this world that even his worn-out, cast-off sword is regarded as a valuable item worth fighting over.

[image] [image]

Comment: this is it thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like ***[Am I Invincible](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/ix6rpma/wo-shenme-shihou-wudile)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> He always thought he was a mortal, but he didn’t know that his yard was full of divine weapons and the chickens he raised were more like phoenixes! It wasn’t until after five years of living in a mortal village when the system finally allowed him to come into contact with cultivators. It was then that he discovered that no matter how strong someone was, the moment they saw him, they would be so scared that their legs gets numb and call him senior. Some even kneeled down and worshipped him…

Five years ago, the protagonist, Chen Pingan, was isekaied from Earth to a world of immortal cultivation. Since then, he's been living a quiet life in a mortal town with a game system that rewards him with seemingly everyday items for completing mundane tasks, but he's been frustrated by his inability to learn cultivation and get stronger.

Now, his system directs him to join an immortal sect and he wonders how he'll get in as a mortal. When he arrives at the sect though, everyone there is awestruck by him, as he's glowing with spiritual energy from their POV. At one point, he pulls out a small knife which is also radiating spiritual energy from their POV, and the sect leader calls it a legendary artifact.

[image] [image]

Comment: i know this one but its not this  the guy gave his broken knife away, he has a gym of sort  and his paintinhs give enlightenment

Answer (score -1):

**I am cultivation big shot**
This character (mc) get isekai'd and has a system which practically made him a god but he doesn't get it.
He is a dense character with God level.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this question has already been definitively answered (note the green check mark next to the top answer). As such, your suggestion is not correct. Please consider taking the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how the site works

Comment: Although, a good (detailed) answer that also matches the question is fine, as it might help other people searching for similar stories. It really does have to be more than just a name and a cover image, though, to provide searchable hooks.